# Quip Thread Search API returning 0 results

Tags: quip, liveapps

Using the Quip API endpoint:
https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/search

I keep getting an empty result.

https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/search?query=Example
https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/search?query="Example"

I've also noticed that the API docs state a POST (which returns a 503) vs. a GET (which returns a 200 but an empty array).

Has anyone been able to make this API endpoint work?

Access Token is working fine for other endpoints. I'm using the Personal Token for this at the moment in case that might be the reason.

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET to .../search?query="string to query" is the only way I can get this route to work. The [Quip Documentation](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#threads-search) verb says POST but curl example is clearly a GET. Looks like a simple verb typo.

An empty array... this simply means there are no matching threads. Try a different query.

Documentation aside, GET is just how this particular route appears to work as of 20MAR19.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, looks like the search might need a bit of propagation time, the new docs I created didn't appear for awhile. Thanks for the feedback!